# Count Total from Multiple Tables Mysql Query

Tags: mysql, sql, database, database-design, relational-database

I have list table that basically contains same field on each part.

```
- p_xl_cj_ticket_m_site_data      |  - p_xl_cj_ticket     |  - p_xl_cj_ticket_last_row_ingroup
- p_xl_jabo1_ticket_m_site_data   |  - p_xl_jabo1_ticket  |  - p_xl_jabo1_ticket_last_row_ingroup
- p_xl_jabo2_ticket_m_site_data   |  - p_xl_jabo2_ticket  |  - p_xl_jabo2_ticket_last_row_ingroup
```

What should i do if i want to count all total sites from ticket1, ticket2, ticket3 ?

> Expected Output (Total from 3 tables above):

[image]

The current code:

```
SELECT COUNT( * ) AS tot_sites, 
       IFNULL( COUNT( 
            CASE WHEN p_xl_cj_m_site_data.m_date_target = DATE( NOW( ) ) 
            THEN 1 ELSE NULL END ) , 0 ) AS todays_target, 
       IFNULL( COUNT( 
            CASE WHEN (p_xl_cj_m_site_data.m_date_target = DATE( NOW( ) ) 
                       AND p_xl_cj_ticket.t_status =9 ) 
            THEN 1 ELSE NULL END ) , 0) AS todays_achieve, 
       IFNULL( COUNT( 
            CASE WHEN p_xl_cj_ticket.t_status =9
            THEN 1 ELSE NULL END ) , 0 ) AS tot_in
FROM p_xl_cj_m_site_data
LEFT JOIN p_xl_cj_ticket_last_row_ingroup  
        ON p_xl_cj_ticket_last_row_ingroup.t_m_id = p_xl_cj_m_site_data.m_id
       AND p_xl_cj_ticket_last_row_ingroup.t_req_type =  '04_int_finish_ack'
LEFT JOIN p_xl_cj_ticket 
        ON p_xl_cj_ticket.t_id = p_xl_cj_ticket_last_row_ingroup.t_id
WHERE p_xl_cj_m_site_data.m_status =1
```

Sample Data:

```
p_xl_cj_ticket_m_site_data       p_xl_cj_ticket        p_xl_cj_ticket_last_row_ingroup     
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------  
* m_date_target = 2019-02-13    * t_status = 9         * t_m_id = xxxxx123
* m_status = 1                  * t_id = abc           * t_id = abc
* m_id = xxxxx123                                      * t_req_type = 04_int_finish_ack
```

My current code is just count ticket for p_xl_cj.

How should i do, if want to make output like my expectation ?

Thanks...

Comment: Let us help you, post sample data and expected output for this data

Comment: This kind of problem is symptomatic of poor design

Comment: What data that u want, i'll provide it @RadimBača

Comment: Just post some exampe table (with data) and expected output that we can clearly understand what you are up to

Comment: @RadimBača i've already added sample data for p_xl_cj, i still have p_xl_jabo1, p_xl_jabo2 type. but it contains same with p_xl_cj. Like my expectation above, i want to query total count

Comment: You have three tables, right? What table is `p_xl_cj_m_site_data` in your code? You say "My current code is just count ticket for p_xl_cj", what is `p_xl_cj`? Your question lacks clarity.

Comment: it just the way to simplify write the name man, i have p_xl_cj_m_site_data, p_xl_jabo1_m_site_data, p_xl_jabo2_m_site_data. i said p_xl_cj just to cut the _m_site_data. But its okay, im sorry to confusing you @RadimBača

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT  (
    SELECT COUNT(*)
    FROM   <table>
    ) AS count1,
    (
    SELECT COUNT(*)
    FROM   <table>
    ) AS count2
```

Comment: Can you please add some further explanation to this, other than the code, to help the OP understand why your answer would work.